# Use .map() to iterate array inside a object React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to iterate throw elements in a Array of objects, but since the returned data is not an Array but a Object, .map() can't be used in the simple way.

API returns the following structure

/players (endpoint)

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "player_id": "Uy2sZ5ef",
      "player_name": "Foo",
      "player_team": "5c50bae023213348c4453aaf"      
    },
    {      
      "player_id": "h15sqI4D",
      "player_name": "Foo 2",
      "player_team": "5c50bae023213348c4453aaf"
    }
  ]
}
```

React component

```
export class Players extends Component {
    state = {
        players: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    API.get(`players/`).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({ players: res.data })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="contents">

                { this.state.players.map(player => <li>{player.player_name}</li>)}

            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Console error]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data looks like that object, and you need only players, you should:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    API.get(`players/`).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({ players: res.data.players }) // <-- get only the players
        })
    }
```

Comment: That's correct, I was unable to find it. After Stackoverflow's delay to accept this answer, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in functional component:

```
const Players = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    API.get(`players/`).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      setPlayers(res.data.players); // <-- get only the players
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="contents">
      {players.map(player => (
        <li>{player.player_name}</li>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Indeed we all should work with functional components !